# Text with partially overlapping characters

Tags: formatting

I would like to reproduce the text of the following image using TeX. Essentially, all the characters are partially overlapping each other.

[image]

I am not sure how to exactly call this type of formatting, so I couldn't look it up. Also, if the closest resembling font package can be pointed out, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you use pdflatex or lualatex or xelatex or ...?

Comment: Have a look at `fontspec` and the `LetterSpace` option.

Comment: @TeXnician mostly pdflatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pdflatex you can do it with microtype:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}

\textls[-100]{2345 Some Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved with `fontspec` package. You should use `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX` to compile.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[LetterSpace=-12]{Latin Modern Roman}



\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```